# Maintaining Sticky Session in Azure Web App for Linux Container

Tags: sticky-session, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have an Azure Web App for Linux Container with PHP Web Application deployed as a single Container. This Azure Web App is running with minimum of two of instance and is setup to auto scale. This Web Application uses sticky session. Does the Azure Web App for Linux Container supports it? Is there any way I can set it up in Azure Web App for Linux Container?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please give the response.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I am trying this out.I should be good for now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the Azure Web App for Linux Container supports the sticky session. But in the Web App, it calls **ARR affinity**, if you need the sticky session, just enable it. In addition, it's enabled in default. You can take look at the document [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/05/16/Disable-Session-affinity-cookie-(ARR-cookie)-for-Azure-web-apps.html). You can enable it if it was disabled:

[image]